# PayPal subscriptions PDT / IPN - PLEASE

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-processing

Am having a lot of trouble getting my head around this paypal payment stuff...

**How can i confirm that the user has successfully signed up for my subscription?**

I know 0 about IPN but for example : If a user signs up to my website with example@e.com but uses the paypal account sample@s.com to pay then how to i match up the user.

I read that PDT do not send out a transaction ID (tx) for recurring (subscription) payments is that true ?

Just need help with it all... honest and easy :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah sometimes is hard to understand Paypal and all their documentation but for any kind of subscription i would recommend Paypal IPN. You set IPN URL in your paypal account for example: http://www.domain.com/ipn.php. Then you create a subscription button in paypal account where you can set the price, recurring price etc.

More about Paypal IPN you can read here:
https://www.paypal.com/ipn

When creating Paypal button you can also add some custom fields which can help you determine which customer really pays. So for example you have a database of users and there is user with userid=100, username=Nickname and registered_email=xxx@gmail.com. Now you can decide to add userid=100 as a custom field and add this to paypal button. For example CUSTOM=100.

ipn.php in this case is a script which handles all the logic. When user pay, Paypal send any status to http://www.domain.com/ipn.php (you set this in your paypal account as IPN URL). So ipn.php in this case needs to check if payment is complete and status is ok. Then retrieve a CUSTOM field ($_POST['custom']) which is in this case 100 (userid). And then update your database with users and somehow mark that this user payed of course if status is Completed.

Hope this helps a little. But in this case it's not really important from which paypal account user pays and which is registered in your database. All you need is that you somehow link it together. In this case with userid or something like that.

Comment: in case of test when using sandbox, which return URL, and account should we use? thanks

Comment: Yeah thats another pain :) You register a new sandbox account using your REAL email address (https://developer.paypal.com/). After that you login with your email and password into paypal SANDBOX account and then you can create different TEST accounts there. You can create one business account for example and 1 or more personal accounts. Remember this is TEST accounts only but works as REAL accounts really. Once you are loged into paypal sandbox click on newly created business account and set IPN URL like in real Paypal account. You can also generate payment buttons there.

Comment: Then create at least one TEST user's account so you can try if payments really works. When testing you just need to change HTML source code of the button from business=YOUR_REAL_EMAIL_or_YOUR_REAL_BUSINESS_CODE into email address or business code of your business TEST account (from paypal sandbox). Also in your IPN file (ipn.php - which you set it as IPN URL) you need to change URL where you post data back to paypal. So instead of real Paypal URL you use sandbox url. Check here for PHP sample: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

Comment: Or check here for other samples: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples Sorry english is not my native language but i hope it's more clear now? Also make sure when testing your payment procedure you need to be logged into your sandbox account and of course for testing payment you use one of PERSONAL accounts which you can create it in your paypal sandbox account. I know it's complicated but not really my fault thats how paypal works really. I just want to make it easier for you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement Paypal IPN and your customers don't use same email from my experience you can use a form to authenticate the user

- user login on your website with xxx@example.org
- user clicks on your item and pays with yyy@example.org
- after he pays you can redirect him to a form where they can merge Paypal account with website account
- every time that user pays then your IPN will be covered by the information he provided
- you should save his payment information for later use.